# Android Room One to many relation query reverse

Tags: android, kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room

I have a One to Many relation between two objects.
I have, lets say, a `user` that have `many` `pets`.

Using this I can retrieve my object

```
data class UserWithPets (
        @Embedded
        var user: User? = null,

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "user_id", entity = Pet::class)
        var pets: List<Pet>? = null
)
```

UserDao:

```
@Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
fun getUserWithPets() : LiveData<List<UserWithPets>>
```

This is working correctly.
Now I want to get the list of Pet with each User associated... Something that would be `PetWithUser`.

So I did:

```
data class PetWithUser (
        @Embedded
        var pet: Pet? = null,

        @Relation(parentColumn = "user_id", entityColumn = "id", entity = Pet::class)
        var user: User? = null
)
```

PetDao:

```
@Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM pets")
fun getPetsWithUser(): LiveData<List<PetWithUser>>
```

As soon as I add the `getPetsWithUser` to the code I get errors with the DataBinding class generation.

How can I do a One to Many relation and get the `pet` with the `user` ?

**edit:**

Error log: They are from the DataBinding java files generated. The second one (HomeFragmentDataBinding) does not use the `PetWithUser` but raise error when `PetWithUser` is added to the code...

```
error: cannot find symbol
  protected ListItemBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                   ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ListItemBinding

error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class FragmentHomeBinding
```

Comment: Are you able to get some information from error? Can you post some error log

Comment: I have a doubt. A user can have many Pets. Similarly, can a Pet belong to multiple users? For example, can a dog(say A) belongs to multiple user (user1, user2)?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. A User can have many Pets (yes !). A Pet can have only 1 User. I would like to get the list of all Pets in db with its associated User.

Answer (score 1):

Correct version would be:

```
data class PetWithUser (
    @Embedded
    var pet: Pet,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "owner_id", entityColumn = "user_id")
    var user: User? = null
)
```

where

- *owner_id* is id of `User` defined in `Pet` class
- *user_id* is matching user id defined in `User` class

Answer (score 0):

You've probably long since figured this out, but it looks like your only problem was that you put down Pet class on your Relation line instead of User class:

```
@Relation(parentColumn = "user_id", entityColumn = "id", entity = Pet::class)
        var user: User? = null
```

instead of

```
@Relation(parentColumn = "user_id", entityColumn = "id", entity = User::class)
        var user: User? = null
```